# How do I restrict the movement of a point to within an area of polygon?

Tags: javascript, math, html5-canvas, geometry

I have a point and I need to constrain movement of this point within a complex polygon.

[image]

https://wrf.ecse.rpi.edu//Research/Short_Notes/pnpoly.html
This algorithm is returning true when point is in polygon but I need to get coordinates of point when it's not.

If it's not making any sense here is application that I'm referring to: [Graphing Calculator](https://beta.geogebra.org/graphing)

1) Tools->Polygons->Polygon
2) Tools->Points->Point on object

I am using pure javascript and html5 canvas. Thanks for any suggestions and sorry for my bad english. If I am missing something please feel free to ask me any questions in comments.

Comment: What did you try first?

Comment: @Ahmad I am using this algorithm https://wrf.ecse.rpi.edu//Research/Short_Notes/pnpoly.html